# Recognize a sequence of elements with minimum and maximum duration

Tags: system.reactive

Given a `IObservable<bool>`,and two `TimeSpan` thresholds, `minDuration` and `maxDuration`, I need to transform the sequence so that:

- A sequence of true values that spans a time between `minDuration` and `maxDuration` transforms to "x"
- A sequence of true values that spans more than `maxDuration` transforms to "y"; "y" should be emitted after `maxDuration` time passed since the first true value was emitted

To make things clearer, assuming `minDuration = 3`, `maxDuration = 6`, and assuming items are emitted at the speed of one per second:

`fffttffttfftttttttttttffftttffffttttf`

`------------------y--------x-------x-`

My guess is that I need to implement a custom operator, but as a RX newbie I don't know how, and I'm having a hard time finding examples that go beyond composing the existing operator with an extension method.

Links to tutorials and examples on implementing custom operators are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this right:

1. When you get consecutive true values for more than the `minDuration` but less than the `maxDuration`, you want to emit `x`.
2. When you get consecutive true values for more than the `maxDuration`, you want to emit `y`.
3. In any other scenario, emit nothing.

If that's the case, your marble diagram should look more like this:

```
fffttffttfftttttttttttffftttffffttttf
           1234567       123    1234  (numbers for counting guidance)
-----------------y----------x-------x (mine)
------------------y--------x-------x- (yours)
```

The `x` can only come out on the false. You can't emit it on the true, because you don't know what a future value will be! No custom operator can solve that for you.

The rest could be solved with this:

```
    var values = new List<bool> // matches fffttffttfftttttttttttffftttffffttttf
    {
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
    };

    var original = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Where(i => i < values.Count)
        .Select(i => values[(int)i]);
    TimeSpan minDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    TimeSpan maxDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6);

    var trueWindows = original
        .TimeInterval()
        .Scan(TimeSpan.Zero, (a, t) => t.Value
            ? a + t.Interval
            : TimeSpan.Zero);
    var coupledWindows = trueWindows.Scan(new {Previous = TimeSpan.Zero, Current = TimeSpan.Zero},
        (o, t) => new {Previous = o.Current, Current = t})
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();
    var xS = coupledWindows.Where(o => o.Previous < maxDuration && o.Previous >= minDuration && o.Current == TimeSpan.Zero).Select(t => "X");
    var yS = coupledWindows.Where(o => o.Current >= maxDuration && o.Previous < maxDuration).Select(t => "Y");
```

As for tutorials, the best resource is http://introtorx.com/. Another somewhat good one is http://rxmarbles.com, though it uses non-.NET function names.

Comment: Great answer, but it bothers me why SO "IntelliSense" can't process your code? :-)

Comment: Yeah, bothers me also now. I just tried adding [language tags](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), but doesn't seem to help at all.